# Magento set "Show All" products by specific category (or in .phtml) rather than globally

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I'm aware of the setting in the admin panel for the default number of products to show on the category list pages. This appears to be a global setting for the whole store. I'm looking for a way to set this on a per category basis (e.g. have most categories default to 25 products per page, but one specific category default to showing all products on the first page). Ideally this would be done in admin or in a .phtml file if possible. How can I set the default products per page for a specific category?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look in

design/package/theme/catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml

The items per page select drop down is generated by a for loop around:

```
$this->getAvailableLimit()
```

The block for the toolbar has the following method on it:

```
public function getLimitUrl($limit)
{
    return $this->getPagerUrl(array(
        $this->getLimitVarName() => $limit,
        $this->getPageVarName() => null
    ));
}
```

The trick is to do one of the two following:

1) leverage magento to build the proper url when it is injected in any link directing to the category you want to be in view all mode.

2) on the /catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml block check the current category, if the current category is the desired category execute the following code:

```
if( strtoupper($this->getLimitVarName()) != "ALL" )
{
  $viewAllUrl =  $this->getLimitUrl('All');
  $this->_redirectUrl( $viewAllUrl );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At Admin Panel

Go to -> CMS -> Pages -> Home Page

Click on "Content" tab on LEFT

Click on "Show/Hide Editor" Button at RIGHT

Copy - Paste This Code there :

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list"  category_id="2" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

Give Category ID of your desired Category

To check Category_id of any category Go to : Catalog Menu -> Manage Catagories

Click on category, at right side's TITLE somewhat like will be displayed :

"CATEGORY_NAME ( ID : 5 )"

Regards.

Comment: Hi Ravi - thanks for your response but I'm not trying to add a product list to my home page. I'm trying to change one specific category list page to show "ALL" products in that category, rather than showing a limited number of products and having a "Next page" button.